# How can create Android app using Django REST API

Tags: android, python, django

How can create an Android App with Django back-end.
I have created  REST API but unable to communicate between Android and API. Any luck...Thanks in advance..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so the community can help you.

Comment: You can use Retrofit for Android for easy integration. Also test all your api endpoints locally by sending request in apps like postman or just by curl, depends on your choice. You should learn Rest api syntax (start from wikipedia article) and then build your endpoints (urls) and check them in built-in api view of django rest (runserver).

Answer (score 0):

Communicating to your REST-API should be made via SSL-encrypted calls to your specified endpoints like https://myurl.com/api/call_method

You can use androids HttpUrlConnection to access your server. Preprocess your user input in a task specific handler and start an AsyncTask to your server. You can authenticate the user i.e. with an google or facebook OAuth2 login with backend verfication if your data should be protected. You can return a JSON to your app and process the data from there on.

All those single steps have great documentation or SO posts already. When you have a specific problem, come back with the exact question.